# Follow up to earlier solution of ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I posted earlier about implementing a list view in android, which I managed to get working. But for some reason the list view isn't scrollable and I know they are suppose to be be default. Can any one explain why?

The code I am using is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950909/adding-to-listview)

Thanks

Comment: Home many items are in the list?

Comment: It depends upon what is returned by the asycnTask. It gets the number of useful rows from a table, this is usually around 10, and places them in the list. What you think?

Comment: Could you post your updated code?

Comment: I think android:layout_height must be fill_parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - it was my mistake. I assumed that the list should be scrollable regardless of the number of items in it. Originally the list only had 10 items which didn't take up the entire screen thus the list wasn't scrollable. Once it increased it became scrollable.